# pyglet Python function will not return or bail

Tags: function, python-3.x, pyglet

I am attempting a random sound looper to play bird calls to attract birds to my feeder. Where I am at in this process is just creating a function that will play a sound and then return. I intend to introduce pseudo-randomness both is volume and repetition next.

Here is the code I am using to attempt a function to play a random sound.

```
#!usr/bin/env python
#coding=utf-8    

import pyglet
import os
import random    


def playBirdSound():
    target_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "birdcallSounds")
    fileList = os.listdir(target_dir)
    target_file = os.path.join(target_dir, fileList[random.randrange(0, len(fileList))])
    song = pyglet.media.load(target_file)
    song.play()
    pyglet.app.run()    


if __name__ == '__main__':    

    playBirdSound()
    print("test trace print")
```

So far my I have only been able to get the a sound to play. But my function never returns to print my "test trace print".

Answer (score 0):

`pyglet.app.run()` creates an infinite loop until the application is closed. Just move it to the end of the file.